# Cannot connect to Sql server from .net core application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core, connection-string

I am working on .net core application, which will connect to database to fetch records.

here is the connection string:

> Server=NEWGGHEG1RDMDBI.id.Test.test1.COM\FF1,3133;Database=T1;Integrated Security=False;User
>   Id=AMR\s_testuser;Password=test@123;Persist Security
>   Info=True;

when i try connecting to database using this connectionstring, it says Login Failed to user 'AMR\s_testuser'.

Username and password which i am passing are correct.

I tried many answers, but nothing worked.
Please help me on this.
Thank you

Comment: `AMR\s_testuser` looks to be a domain account. You can't pass that account in the connection string. To connect using a Windows account, you need to run the process under that account or impersonate.

Comment: How should i pass that account ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and your error message, you are using the wrong authentication. If you created the user inside SQL Server then you should be using standard security. If you are using a domain account, which you show in your connection string, you need to be using trusted connection.

### Standard

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`

### Trusted

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`

Notice that trusted does not pass any credentials where as standard does.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the Domain Account has access to the database server?  There should be a corresponding Login on the server for the domain User/Group attempting to connection. In addition to this, there would need to be a database user mapped to the login and granted the appropriate permissions/roles on the target database (T1)

[Create a Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-2017)

[Create a Database User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017)

Give the following connection string a try:

```
Server=NEWGGHEG1RDMDBI.id.Test.test1.COM\FF1,3133;Database=T1;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: domain account has access to database server

Comment: but when i set Integrated security=false; it take userid and password,but says login failed for user

Comment: Is this SQL Server on the same domain/network or is this an Azure SQL database?